# Parse query result to insert it into another database

Tags: python, mysql, sql

After running a query from a MySQL database I het the following result:

```
(datetime.date(2000, 11, 11), u'superuser', datetime.date(2000, 11,11),u'yes')
(datetime.date(2001, 11, 11), u'superuser', datetime.date(2001, 11,11),u'yes')
(datetime.date(2002, 11, 11), u'superuser', datetime.date(2002, 11,11),u'yes')
(datetime.date(2003, 11, 11), u'superuser', datetime.date(2003, 11,11),u'yes')
```

Those results comes from a databse which has four columns:

```
last_login | is_superuser | data_joined | is_active
```

My problem is that I need to insert those data in another database that has the same structure, but I need to parse the data in a way that MySQL will be able to accept the query:

```
 INSERT INTO  auth_user.auth_user (last_login, is_superuser, data_joined, 
 is_active) VALUES 
    ('2008-11-11', 'superuser', '2008-11-11', 'yes'),
    ('2008-11-11', 'superuser', '2008-11-11', 'yes'),
    ('2008-11-11', 'superuser', '2008-11-11', 'yes'),
    ('2008-11-11', 'superuser', '2008-11-11', 'yes')[...];
```

I am struggling to obtain this format from the previous one, does anyone has any suggestion how to approach this problem?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42039794/inserting-a-list-holding-multiple-values-in-mysql-using-pymysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`executemany()`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id18) and a parameterized query. Given that the results from the previous query are stored as a list of tuples named `results`:

```
query = """INSERT INTO  auth_user.auth_user
           (last_login, is_superuser, data_joined, is_active)
           VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"""

# If your driver's cursors don't work as context managers, wrap with
# contextlib.closing
with conn.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.executemany(query, results)

conn.commit()
```

Your driver knows how to pass the usual Python objects, such as `date`, `datetime`, strings, and numbers when using parameterized queries.

Depending on the driver in use `executemany()` may or may not optimize passing multiple value tuples. For example [MySQL Connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html) and [PyMySQL](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.Cursor.executemany) optimize INSERT statements.

Comment: This would work, but how can I gt ride of the datetime.date, u' and so on?

Comment: It seems I get an attribute error when I try to execute this, the error message I get is __exit__

Comment: yes, i do:  `try:
                logging.info(' Trying to execute the query...')
                cursor = db_connection.cursor()
                cursor.executemany(query_string, query_data)
                db_connection.commit()

                logging.info(' Query executed!')
                db_connection.close()
                return logging.info('Connection closed!') `

Comment: I was wrong with the logged query, basically everything I get no error, and everything looks fine, but the data are not getting copied. My driver is MySQL and for the connection I use `mysql.connector.Connect`

Comment: Ok, I think I am doing something wrong (as always) it seems like that I am duplicating the same data on the same DB instead of copying it to another one...

Answer (score 1):

Your results are tuples... just produce a suitable SQL query, and `execute()` it:

```py
query = 'INSERT INTO auth_user.auth_user'                       \
          ' (last_login, is_superuser, data_joined, is_active)' \
          ' VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s);'

for result in results:
    cursor.execute(query, result)
```